# The problem of GLCM parameters in gee

Tags: google-earth-engine

When I use glcm to calculate texture features, I use the code `glcmTexture({size: 1, kernel:ee.Kernel.square(1), average:false});` The result is 72 bands, which is due to 18 components with 4 direction multiplication. When the code is modified to `glcmTexture({size: 3, kernel:ee.Kernel.square(3), average:false});`, why does it get 432 bands?

In addition, why must the value of size be greater than or equal to the value of kernel?